# Sometime while crypting data my code returns specific result with strange symbols

Tags: python, encryption

I'm learning cryptography with python3

Now I'm working on Caesar Cipher and here is my problem

I try to crypt "hdjdyueeje"   using key 16
and that is a result "zwzt??uuzu"

can you please explain me what I'm doing wrong and what to do to fix it

my code:

```
print("\n----------------Caesar_Cipher----------------\n")

print('  1) Crypt mode')
print("  2) Decrypt mode")

try:
    mode = int(input('\n  [#]  Enter number what you need (1,2) : '))

    if mode == 1:
        print("\n--------Crypting process is starting---------")
        key = int(input("\n  [#]  Enter here key which will be used to crypt data \n       (number from 1 to 25 including) --> "))

        if 1 >= key or key > 25:
            print("   You choosed wrong number. I will make it 1 automatically")  
            key = 1
        else:
            pass

        msg = input("\n  [#]  Now enter your message what you wanna crypt \
                \n    -->")
        print("")

        msgc = ""
        for letter in msg:
            x = ord(letter)
            y = chr(x + key)
            msgc += y

        print('\n Crypted data -->',msgc)
    elif mode == 2:
        print("\n-------Decrypting process is starting--------")

        key = int(input("\n  [#]  Enter here key which will be used to decrypt data \n       (number from 1 to 25 including) --> "))

        if 1 >= key or key > 25:
            print("   You choosed wrong number. I will make it 1 automatically")  
            key = 1
        else:
            pass

        msg = input("\n  [#]  Now enter your message what you wanna decrypt \
                \n    -->")
        print("")
        msgd = ""
        for letter in msg:
            x = ord(letter)
            y = chr(x - key)
            msgd += y

        print('\n Decrypted data -->',msgd)
    else:
        print("Number not defined")
```

that's all

Comment: ord and chr work with every single unicode charcter, not just the alphabet, so your program is working as intended

Comment: in Caesar Cipher with key 16 (and 26 chars in alphabet) char with number 20 goes to 10 because  "20+16 modulo 26" gives 10 - but you get 36 because you do  only "20+16" - so you can get number of strange symbol instead of char in alphabet. You forgot to take modulo.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
x = ord(letter)
y = chr(x + key) # <- problem
msgc += y
```

If there not enough letters left with a higher code the alphabet needs to wrap around. For example when you try to encrypt `y` you can only add 1 to get to `z`. If the key would be 2 you would need to wrap around and go back to `a`. This "wrapping around" can easily be done by subtracting the length of the alphabet. This version of the code works:

```
x = ord(letter)
y = x + key
if y > ord('z'):
    y -= 26
msgc += chr(y)
```

Be aware that this only works for lower case letters.